# Why does my form only submit on the second click?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why isn't the form submitted the first time?
What have I done wrong?

If I click submit, the console will display the output (Event check # 0. Event check # 1.)
If I click on the submit button again, the console will display the output (Event check # 0. Event check # 1. Event check # 2.)
And after that the message will be sent to the mail.

[image]

".button-f" and "# send-btn-form" are the same button!

```
//#1grn --- Submitting the form without reloading the page
let sendBtn = document.querySelector(".button-f");
sendBtn.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Cancels the default browser action
    console.log("Event check №0.");

    let formName = document.querySelector('#main-form'); // Find our shape
    let formData = new FormData(formName); // Create a new FormData-object. We use all fields with the attribute name
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create a new XMLHttpRequest-object.
    request.open('POST', "php/send.php"); // We configure it: POST-request for URL php/send.php

    //#1grn --- Filtering characters such as: &<>"'
    ['name', 'socialname', 'numberfo', 'email', 'text'].forEach(name => {
        let input = document.querySelector(`[name='${name}']`);
        input.value = escape(input.value);
        console.log("Event check №1.");
    });

    //#1grn --- Check ("real" event or generated by code)
    let sendBttn = document.querySelector("#send-btn-form");
    sendBttn.addEventListener('click', e => { // We accept the event object into our callback-function, call it "e".
        if (e.isTrusted) { // CHECKING, if a e.isTrusted === true - then this is not a machine click.
            request.send(formData); // We send HTTP request to the server and get a response.
            console.log("Event check №2.");
        } else {
            console.log('blocked!');
        }
    });

    // This code will work after we receive the server response
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP-response status, if the status is not 200, then an error has occurred
        } else { // if everything went smoothly, clear the form and display the result
            formName.reset(formData); // Clearing the form
            let on = document.querySelector(".message-good");
            on.classList.add('ms-on');
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Because you don't add the event handler that actually submits the form until you click it the first time?

Comment: move `sendBttn.addEventListener('click',` outside of your current onclick function

Comment: Why are you even adding a second click handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ".button-f" and "#send-btn-form" are the same button, you are adding an event listener every time you click the button. In that case, you are not executing the code inside that listener, it will be executed the next time you click it. So you could replace this

```js
let sendBttn = document.querySelector("#send-btn-form");
sendBttn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.isTrusted) {
        request.send(formData);
    } else {
        console.log('blocked!');
    }
});
```

with just this

```js
if (e.isTrusted) {
    request.send(formData);
} else {
    console.log('blocked!');
}
```

Comment: Yes ".button-f" and "# send-btn-form" are the same button.
If I remove this, then how will my verification take place? (Was it a real click or was it a bot)
let sendBttn = document.querySelector ("# send-btn-form");
sendBttn.addEventListener ('click', e => {

Comment: `sendBtn.onclick = function(e)` is the same as `sendBtn.addEventListener('click', e =>`, and I'm not sure about how any of those could check if it was a bot or a user who clicked... I think they both will fail at checking that

Comment: The `isTrusted` read-only property of the `Event` interface is a `Boolean` that is `true` when the event was generated by a user action, and `false` when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`

Comment: Oh alright, so look at my example, when it does `if (e.isTrusted)` that `e` is comming from the `onclick` event, so I think you'll be fine with it... In any case, always be careful about where an `addEventListener` is placed because it can harm the performance and it can also work wierd

Comment: Yes thank you man! It worked! I checked all the functions and they work including the check from the bot. Yes i understood where had this problem. You rarely use `addEventListener`?

Comment: Glad I could help! I use React so I rarely (actually never) use addEventListener... But it is ok to use it as long as you are careful about it... About difference between onclick and addEventListener('click'), I've found this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/6750370](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/6750370) Hope it helps